# Create POCO objects from entity framework database first

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, poco

I have a simple entity framework model that connects to my existing database.

[image: ADO.NET Entity Data Model]

Every user can have multiple tickets and every ticket can have multiple sub-tickets (recursively).

The problem is that entity framework generates its own c# models with annotations and additional functions that make the model strictly dependent on entity framework.

I want to create my own models (POCO's) which would be independent of the framework/orm that i use, for example:

```
class Ticket {

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public User User { get; set; }

    public Ticket Parent { get; set; }

    public IList<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; }
}
```

No annotations and no additional functions.

I also want to be able to use lazy loading on my models.

How can i do it?

Thanks,
Arik

Comment: Have you looked into EF code first to existing database? (VS can reverse-engineer a code first model for you)

Comment: @lc. i just tried doing it and it generates entities for me but it still puts entity framework annotations on those entities.

Comment: You can usually get away with find-replacing them. Like you can change Column attributes to use DataType attributes instead (which play very nicely with MVC validation for example), then use a convention in your EF configuration to translate them back. Not a perfect answer but I've just actually come from doing a very similar thing.

Comment: Hmmm, I just reverse engineered a large database. Using the right tools it created the POCOs with no annotations and a single model class with all the fluent api statements. EF 6 Tools: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40762 C# Templates: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/dn753860